# T/SQL Puzzle - How to join to create one-to-one relationship for two unrelated tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

Let's assume that I have two tables...  Foo and Bar.  They contain the following data.

```
Table Foo:
Foo_Id
------
100
101

Table Bar:
Bar_Id
------
200
201
```

As you can see, each table has two records.  I'd like to join these tables together in a way where they return two records; the ultimate goal is to create a one to one relationship for these records even though at this state they do not have that relationship.  The results of this data would go into table Foo_Bar to store this new relationship.

Ideally, the output would look similar to the following.

```
Foo_Id  Bar_Id
------  ------
100     200
101     201
```

This code will be used in a T/SQL stored procedure.  I could write this easily with a while loop, but I would prefer not to use a while loop because the real world application will have a lot more data than four records and will by called by multiple users many times per day.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

It's more or less an inventory problem... I've got 100 slices of pizza and 100 people who say they want a slice of pizza. The Foo_Bar table is basically a way to assign one slice of pizza per person. The table exists and this solution will load the data for the table.

Comment: A). I think you've got the answer in your question B). why would you want to create a relationship where one doesn't exist? Either there is a relationship and it should be appropriately modelled or there isn't.

Comment: How is the data related?   Can any Foo_Id go with any Bar_Id?

Comment: It's more or less an inventory problem...  I've got 100 slices of pizza and 100 people who say they want a slice of pizza.  The Foo_Bar table is basically a way to assign one slice of pizza per person.  The table exists and this solution will load the data for the table.

Comment: If a foo_bar table exists, they you already have a relationship (albeit a badly modeled one) and it is a simple matter of joining through it. So where is the problem?

Comment: @JohnFx - This is currently a manual process and it's been requested to automated if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
declare @Foo table (Foo_Id int)
INSERT INTO @Foo VALUES (100)
INSERT INTO @Foo VALUES (101)
declare @Bar table (Bar_Id int)
INSERT INTO @Bar VALUES (200)
INSERT INTO @Bar VALUES (201)


SELECT
    dt_f.Foo_Id
        ,dt_f.RowNumber
        ,dt_b.Bar_Id
    FROM (SELECT
              Foo_Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Foo_Id) AS RowNumber
              FROM @Foo
          ) dt_f
        INNER JOIN (SELECT
                        Bar_Id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Bar_Id) AS RowNumber
                        FROM @Bar
                   ) dt_b ON dt_f.RowNumber=dt_b.RowNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

select foo_id, bar_id
from foo inner join bar on foo_id = (bar_id -100)

Comment: it provided a way to answer the problem that was originally posted.

Answer (score 2):

From the example you've given, you might be able to exploit the fact that bar_id = 100 + foo_id

```
select foo.foo_id, bar.bar_id
from foo inner join bar on foo.foo_id +100 = bar.bar_id
```

.. but maybe that is just a simplification in your example?

If there is no relatinship between the IDs, then its not really *relational data* anymore, and there's no easy way to join the rows in a Relational Database.

In which case you would have to add a new column to one of the tables and add a foreign key so that the data *does* become relational.

Comment: yeah, thought it might. The alternative second part of my answer is to add a new column, but I know thats not much better either : )

Answer (score 2):

Assigning to inventory is typically going to be a one row at a time operation. Using sets for this is great but it is kind of a "batch processing" paradigm. I would envision various people get into line and acquire pizza from the inventory table. Mssql has some useful hints for this get-next-available-item pattern - look at the READPAST hint. To acquire a pizza you might do something like

```
UPDATE mytable WITH (READPAST) SET AcquiringUserID = @userId where AcquiringUserId is null
```

Comment: Found an article that goes over this kind of approach - http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1257

Answer (score 0):

select from each table as a nested select statement with a rank function, then join on the rank.

```
select foo_id, bar_id
from (select foo_id, rank() over (partition by foo_id order by foo_id) as [Rank] from foo) f
left join (select bar_id, rank() over (partition by bar_id order by bar_id) as [Rank] from bar) b
on f.Rank = b.Rank
```

Comment: when run on the given sample data, it returns 4 rows. You need to remove the "Partition by foo_id" and "partition by bar_id" to make it work properly.  I use the same approach sing row_number(), see my solution.